# Reshaping Pandas dataframe grouping variables

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a pandas dataFrame in the following format

```
   ID   Name  
0   1    Jim  
1   1  Jimmy  
2   2   Mark  
3   2  Marko  
4   3  Sergi  
4   3  Sergi
```

I want to reshape the dataframe in the following format

```
   ID  Name_1   Name_2  
0   1     Jim    Jimmy  
1   2    Mark    Marko  
2   3   Sergi    Sergi
```

So that I can compare the two names. I am unable to use `pd.pivot` or `pd.pivottable` for this requirement.
Should be fairly simple. Please, can you suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html), last [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) to column names:

```
df['groups'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount() + 1
df = df.pivot(index='ID', columns='groups', values='Name').add_prefix('Name_')
print (df)
groups Name_1 Name_2
ID                  
1         Jim  Jimmy
2        Mark  Marko
3       Sergi  Sergi
```

Another solution with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), last [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) to column names:

```
df1 = df.groupby('ID')["Name"] \
        .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values)) \
        .unstack(1)  \
        .rename(columns=lambda x: x+1) \
        .add_prefix('Name_')
print (df1)
   Name_1 Name_2
ID              
1     Jim  Jimmy
2    Mark  Marko
3   Sergi  Sergi
```

Comment: One more question? I am new to using stackoverflow for pandas. Can you tell me how to represent dataframes when posting a question ?

Comment: so for net row need change from `1     1  Jimmy` to `'    1     1  Jimmy'` (4 spaces before).